# how to loop through JSON array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have a PHP page from which I get response in JSON:

```
[{'com':'something'},{'com':'some other thing'}]
```

I want to loop it and append each to a div.

This is what I tried:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(obj.com, function(key,value) {
  alert(key+':'+value);
}
```

This alerts as `undefined`, and also response is the JSON array..

Comment: @KoIIIeY doesn't show any alert..

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your array has default keys(0,1) which store object `{'com':'some thing'}` 
 use:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
  alert(value.com);
});
```

Comment: Anyway I can fade each? I used `.hide().fadeIn(800);` while appending, but it fades the whole thing at once, is it possible to fade 1 by 1?

Comment: You have to rebind event($(...).bind("")  Or attachEvent()) after(before provide control to user) adding any element.

Comment: I figured it out, I hide all the divs then did a fade in on each, anyway thanks :D

Comment: Syntax error on the last line: needs correct close });

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(data, function(key, item) 
{
   console.log(item.com);
});
```

or

```
var data = $.parseJSON(response);

$(data).each(function(i,val)
 {
    $.each(val,function(key,val)
  {
          console.log(key + " : " + val);     
  });
});
```

Comment: Loops but shows `[object, object]` also I'm getting the json via ajax call

Answer (score 7):

You are iterating through an `undefined` value, ie, `com` property of the Array's object, you should iterate through the array itself:

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
   // here `value` refers to the objects 
});
```

Also note that jQuery intelligently tries to parse the sent JSON, probably you don't need to parse the response.  If you are using `$.ajax()`, you can set the `dataType` to `json` which tells jQuery parse the JSON for you.

If it still doesn't work, check the browser's console for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7):

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   alert(data[i].PageName);
});​

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  alert(item.PageName);
});​
```

Or else You can try this method

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
   alert(value.Id);    //It will shows the Id values
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var data=[{'com':'something'},{'com':'some other thing'}];
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(key, val){
    alert(val);//here data 
      alert (key); //here key

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the key value pair as

```
<pre>
function test(){    
var data=[{'com':'something'},{'com':'some other thing'}];    
$.each(data, function(key,value) {    
alert(key);  
alert(value.com);    
});    
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].com)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var events = [];

alert(doc);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(doc);

     $.each(obj, function (key, value) {

    alert(value.title);
```

});