# How to navigate through this JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object and I want to navigate trought it with javascript or jquery, how can I do that?

```
{
    "Fporder": {
        "cep_id": "300000007",
        "user_id": "300000192",
        "fporder_type_id": 2,
        "agency_id": null,
        "fporder_code": 1,
        "id": "66"
    },
    "FpordersProduct": [
        {
            "product_id": "1938",
            "requested": "4",
            "price": 3965,
            "product_name": "PLANCHA DE LASAGNA PRE COCIDO X KL",
            "product_code": "22044001"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:

Please I'm getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_id' of undefined

I have tried these with no success:

```
json_object.FpordersProduct.product_id
```

OR

```
json_object.FpordersProduct[0].product_id
```

OR

```
json_object.FpordersProduct[0]['product_id']
```

But it does not work. Please Help.

EDIT2

```
function agregar_fporder(fporder)
    {
        console.log('agregar_fporder() ejecutado');
        console.log("fporder: "+fporder);
        var tr = '';
        tr += '<tr class="item fporder">';
        tr +=       '<td class="nro_orden"></td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="id">'+fporder.FpordersProduct.product_id+'</td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="code">'+fporder.FpordersProduct.product_code+'</td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="name">'+fporder.FpordersProduct.product_name+'</td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="nro_pedido">';
        tr +=       '</td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="quantity">';
        tr +=       '</td>';
        tr +=       '<td class="um_id">';
        tr +=       '</td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td>';
        tr +=       '</td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr +=       '<td></td>';
        tr += '</tr>';

        var item = $('table#items tr.items.fporder').find('td.code input.code[value="'+fporder.FpordersProduct.product_code+'"');
        console.log('item: '+item);
    }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: you can also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772417/how-to-loop-through-json-array-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Well, "navigate through it" is very obscure. However, it's an object so if all you need to do is access it's properties, you can do so like any other object.

Examples:

```
var some_json_object = {
  "Fporder": {
    "cep_id": "300000007",
    "user_id": "300000192",
    "fporder_type_id": 2,
    "agency_id": null,
    "fporder_code": 1,
    "id": "66"
  },
  "FpordersProduct": [
    {
      "product_id": "1938",
      "requested": "4",
      "price": 3965,
      "product_name": "PLANCHA DE LASAGNA PRE COCIDO X KL",
      "product_code": "22044001"
    }
  ]
}

some_json_object.Fporder // to access Fporder property on root of object

some_json_object.Fporder.cep_id // to access cep_id property on the object assigned to the Fporder property

some_json_object.FpordersProduct[0] // to access the first (currently only) object on the array assigned to the FpordersProduct property

// ... etc.
```

Comment: And How I access through the first element of some_json_object.FpordersProduct[0], because I'm getting and error doing like this some_json_object.FpordersProduct[0].product_id

Comment: Please show the exact code you're using in your question, including the declaration of your `some_json_object` variable.

Comment: I received that JSON object as a response of a jquery AJAX

Comment: That's fine. So show the code that you're using to handle that response.

Comment: The piece of code you just added is referencing the `fporder` parameter. You said when you tried `json_object.FpordersProduct.product_id` it didn't work. Where is `json_object` defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101343/discussion-between-jeffdill2-and-juanpscotto).