# looping through json object, array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have been trying to loop through json object but it seems i m not getting it. below is the json object. its a json object that will come from another site which i want to loop and get some details.

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Jai Nagar Road",
               "short_name" : "Jai Nagar Road",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Soorpur",
               "short_name" : "Soorpur",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "short_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rajasthan",
               "short_name" : "RJ",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "312023",
               "short_name" : "312023",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Jai Nagar Road, Soorpur, Rajasthan 312023, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0047284,
                  "lng" : 75.0057195
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0006706,
                  "lng" : 75.0015796
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 25.0026729,
               "lng" : 75.00372419999999
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0047284,
                  "lng" : 75.0057195
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0006706,
                  "lng" : 75.0015796
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJZW2OMHBTbzkRRo_IZ8-KtOc",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Chainsingh Ji Ka Rajpura",
               "short_name" : "Chainsingh Ji Ka Rajpura",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "short_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rajasthan",
               "short_name" : "RJ",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "312023",
               "short_name" : "312023",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Chainsingh Ji Ka Rajpura, Rajasthan 312023, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0045601,
                  "lng" : 75.01064
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.98435,
                  "lng" : 74.99471989999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 24.9913835,
               "lng" : 74.99977579999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.0045601,
                  "lng" : 75.01064
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.98435,
                  "lng" : 74.99471989999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJf8czVWNTbzkR8ZR9tJK11fY",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "312023",
               "short_name" : "312023",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "312023, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.134308,
                  "lng" : 75.2009999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.8438019,
                  "lng" : 74.84139999999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 25.0362956,
               "lng" : 75.0143824
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.134308,
                  "lng" : 75.2009999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.8438019,
                  "lng" : 74.84139999999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJc0fixnhUbzkRWCXjs3L0pNw",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "short_name" : "Chittaurgarh",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rajasthan",
               "short_name" : "RJ",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Chittaurgarh, Rajasthan, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.2151799,
                  "lng" : 75.81283000000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.20684,
                  "lng" : 74.10463
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 24.9560515,
               "lng" : 74.6868815
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.2151799,
                  "lng" : 75.81283000000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 24.20684,
                  "lng" : 74.10463
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJmbw1Yl6gaDkRHM-dp2uZAa4",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Rajasthan",
               "short_name" : "RJ",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Rajasthan, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.1932842,
                  "lng" : 78.26338109999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 23.0632669,
                  "lng" : 69.484413
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 27.0238036,
               "lng" : 74.21793260000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.1932842,
                  "lng" : 78.26338109999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 23.0632669,
                  "lng" : 69.484413
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJNw7j9_o-ajkR5YjABkWbK7U",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5087008,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 20.593684,
               "lng" : 78.96288
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5087008,
                  "lng" : 97.39498069999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.7535159,
                  "lng" : 68.16288519999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

please let me know if its possible to loop through this. my problem is i want to track my website visitors. i want exact location of the visitor.
thank you.

Comment: What would be output array you wanted to?

Comment: hi Siddiq, thats a response that came from another page as json and i just want to loop and get the formatted address above. response is coming from this >>>> "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=74,62"

Answer (score -1):

```
// Yes you can apply the loop. First of all you need to decode JSON to an array.
$resultArray = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($resultArray as $row){
 .....

}
```

Comment: hi Muhammad, thanks for quick response. but my problem is  on page 1 i am getting the user cordinates, then i am sending the user cordinates to another page (google) via get method, then when the response comes in json, at this point i was thinking to loop through that json but i cant for some reason i dont know. so i sent to my php page hoping i can convert it but i think i m taking it a long route. please advise if i can directly loop through that json object above without sending again to php.. below is the mess i was doing on my page.

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){
$.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=74,62",function (data1){
var rsp = data1;
$.post("jsontophp.php",{rsp :rsp},function (data){
$("#response").text(data);
});
});
});

Comment: if you want to loop through json from jquery, you can do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772417/how-to-loop-through-json-array-in-jquery. If it is not working, what issue you are facing?